# Symfony2 sonata collection showing empty in edit or show

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

When I create a product I use sonata_type_collection for my relationships... It works like a charm and the values are inserted in the daabase correctly.

However, If I then go to Show or Edit on my product I dont get any errors, but the values are not showing up, like I never added them.

For example:

In my product I can add few categories:

```
->add('category', 'sonata_type_collection',
                array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'label' => 'Category',
                ),
                array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    //'sortable' => 'id',
                )
            )
```

Ant my ProductCategoryAdmin is simple:

```
/**
 * @param FormMapper $formMapper
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('categoryId')
    ;
}
```

So I add 2 categories to my product and create it. They are inserted in the database.

Now if I click edit product it is showing me 0 categories... Why is that? All other collections are working fine, except this category collection.

Answer (score 1):

Does your ProductCategory in your database have both a productId and a categoryId ?
If your product categories doesn't show in both show and edit Product, it seems the productId is not inserted in your ProductCategory.

I usually add 'by_reference' => false on my sonata_type_collection to force all setters to be called.

Official documentation on by_reference : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

With it your code would be :

```
->add('category', 'sonata_type_collection',
    array(
        'required' => false,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'label' => 'Category',
    ),
    array(
        'edit' => 'inline',
        'inline' => 'table',
        //'sortable' => 'id',
    )
)
```

Also, I would have name the field categories instead of category :)